# Is 15 Volts too high of a voltage to run on automotive electrical systems?

Tags: battery, voltage

Is 15 Volts too high of a voltage to run on automotive electrical systems?   And if so,  would filtering the current thru an old style voltage regulator work to lower it to an acceptable voltage ???

Comment: I have prius hybrid 7.5V cells from a battery i broke,down and paired off in groups of 2 all wired in series for a total of 15V which i then wired those pairs together in parallel .

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this?

Comment: 15v is just fine for running 12v systems, many gm cars alternators charge and run the electrical system at 15v+.

Comment: I was worried about that much more V damaging vehicles,  however now that u mention GM alternators,  im once again worried,  because of 1. Those alternators arentt supplying the vehicle itself but rather the battery &2 I distinctly remember way back in Trade School how charging systems monitor batterys V & at  certain threshold the diodes stop current flow.  And that this is especially pertinent to how high output alternators work,  which by ohms law unless resistance is equally increased would not only have high amperage but also high voltage since amps X ohms=Volts and ohms times Amps=volts.

Comment: And as far as why im doing this unless that is a sarcastic or deep philosophical question,    i would think it would  be fairly obvious Im using the cells from electric car batteries for other uses one being as a shallow cycle automotive starting battery ..

Comment: One concern I have would be recharging the batteries. If my understanding is correct, batteries need the rated voltage + a few volts to charge, then float at ~1 volt above their voltage, then set at their rated voltage. If the charge voltage is equal to the battery voltage, the battery won't charge, or will charge very slowly, because current flow only when there's a voltage difference. So while I agree that most electronics will be fine with the increased voltage, I'm not sure the alternator will actually charge the battery.